frame extracted from a video using opencv or ffmpeg is vague, picture i snip from video is clear
I record a video from roadside, and I want to recognize plate license in video. but I find that if I extract every frame from video using python, the frame is too vague to recognize.
I have tried opencv and ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -vframes 1 output.png
`

but if I snip video every second the picture is clear

what's the reason of this phenomenon, how can I fix it
I have tried frame average, it didn't work
